# Что делает метод notifyItemChanged?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview.adapter

Что делает метод `notifyItemChange()` у класса `RecyclerView.Adapter`?

Comment: у какого класса?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman RecyclerView adapter

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для `RecyclerView.Adapter` есть 2 перегрузки данного метода:

---

- **void notifyItemChanged (int position, Object payload)**

Сообщает всем зарегистрированным наблюдателям, что `item` на данной позиции был изменён с необязательным объектом полезной нагрузки.

Это событие изменения позиции, а не событие структурных изменений. Это означает, что любое отражение данных в позиции устарело и должно быть обновлено. `Item` на данной позиции сохраняет идентичность.

Клиент может дополнительно передать полезную нагрузку для частичного изменения. Эти полезные нагрузки будут объединены и могут быть переданы адаптеру в метод `onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder, int, List)`, если элемент уже представлен `ViewHolder`, он будет обновлен внутри того же самого `ViewHolder`. `NotifyItemRangeChanged()` с нулевой полезной нагрузкой очистит все существующие полезные нагрузки на этом элементе и предотвратит будущую полезную нагрузку до вызова `onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder, int, List)`. Адаптер не должен предполагать, что полезная нагрузка всегда будет передаваться в `onBindViewHolder()`. Когда представление не присоединено к `ViewHolder`, полезная нагрузка будет просто удалена.

---

- **void notifyItemChanged(int position)**

Сообщает всем зарегистрированным наблюдателям, что `item` на данной позиции был изменён. Эквивалентно вызову `notifyItemChanged(position, null);`.

Это событие изменения позиции, а не событие структурных изменений. Это означает, что любое отражение данных в позиции устарело и должно быть обновлено. `Item` в позиции сохраняет идентичность.

---

*Вольный перевод сайта [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html)*